# How to put WebAPI and Website (CMS) to same Azure Mobile App container?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api

As stated by Microsoft, they claimed that the new Azure Mobile App can store Website and WebAPI in the same container. However, when I create a Azure App project using VS2015, I can use WebAPI only. If I want to build a website (backend content management system). How can I create it? or upload it?

Does anyone have this experience?

Comment: Can you please add the link the Microsoft website documenting the deployment of both website and webapi in the same container?

Comment: Secondly, it is not clear if you are talking about container service or Azure App Service?  Azure Mobile Apps and Web Apps were merged into the common Azure App service.

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-value-prop-what-is/

Comment: Thanks, I will answer comprehensively below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Azure App Service, if you are using Basic/Standard or Premium plan, you get a dedicated (hidden) host on which you can deploy multiple websites to the same `App Service Plan` or `Web Hosting Plan`. Each website here will have a different sub-domain/custom domain. You are charged on number of App Service Plans, not number of websites.

In the Shared mode, you are charged on number of websites and approximately cost of 4 Shared Websites is equal to cost of a Basic App Service Plan.

However, for some reasons if you wish to host multiple website on the same `Web App`, there is a concept of deployment slots. Typically used to host a staging warmed up new version of the same app, it has a different public sub-domain. Each deployment slot can host a different site.

Comment: Thanks. Now I know what is the use of App Service Plans.